# WebDriver login and click action ain't working...

Tags: selenium2, webdriver

I have the following problem.

I have a website where the Login is Via a Link that has the href: SubmitLogin().

I'm trying to use webdriver in the form of PageFactories.

I have this method:

```
    usernameField.sendKeys(username);
    passwordField.sendKeys(password);
    Reporter.log(String.format("Login with user:%s", username));
    Reporter.log(String.format("Login with password:%s", password));

    //signInLink.click();
    //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //js.executeScript("SubmitLogin");
    signInLink.click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, AdminHomePage.class);
```

As you can see I also tried executing the script directly, but it's no good.

The Page isn't doing anything. I have Javascript enabled and I'm using webdriver with HtmlUnitDriver. Like this:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

The true means that Javascript is enabled.

In the log I can't see any problems. The two fields are set correctly, it finds all the necessary elements it just does nothing. :(

In the log I can see a LOT of css warning and a bunch of severe errors stating that some javascripts failed to execute but none mention SubmitLogin. It just seams that doesn't even reach it or whatever. :S

There is no error on the Page.

I want to use HtmlUnitDriver because this will be running on a desktop less build machine.

Additional Information: It's HTTPS. And also, FirefoxDriver with custom profile handles it just fine. I just would like to use HtmlUnitDriver...

Any ideas? :S

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide html of "signInLink"

Comment: Does your build machine run Unix?

Comment: Sorry that I can answer only now. So... It's a windows machine. And It seems that Javascript is causing the trouble because the page gets loaded. So https couldn't be the cause. I reverted to firefoxdriver for now. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only using HtmlUnitDriver because you don't have a screen, just run the test with the firefox driver and run it headless.  In case you are not familiar with headless it is as simple as running Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24; export DISPLAY=:1   We use headless firefox selenium tests on a hudson server that doesnt have a screen.  Works fine for us

Comment: It's a windows box actually. Yeah I know of headless running, could your elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: I am actually not sure you can run headless Firefox on a Windows box, but if you could it would be your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate the value of being able to run tests on a machine that does not have a desktop.  However, I have never been successful at getting a test that works with a real browser to also work with HtmlUnitDriver.  I would be reluctant to draw any conclusions about the quality of a web application based on the results of running an HtmlUnitDriver-based test.